# Когда сжигаются метки?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, удаление-метки

У нас есть на мете возможность спрашивать про [удаление-метки](/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8).

- А можно в некоторых случаях, которые мне кажутся очевидными, не спрашивать? Если да, то в каких?
- А как понять когда уже можно приступать к удалению?
- Как привлечь внимание к вопросу для удаления, если он будто "повис в воздухе"? Ведь здесь по сути требуется решение "да" или "нет". Может просто стоит спросить Николаса и модераторов в общем чате?
- Если ли у нас какие-то чёткие критерии "ордера на удаления", кроме как спросить Николаса или модераторов в общем чате?
- Единственное, что очевидно, что этого удалять не стоит когда запрос на удаление имеет отрицательную репутацию.

Answer (score 3):

> А можно в некоторых случаях, которые мне кажутся очевидными, не спрашивать? Если да, то в каких?

Если у метки пять использований и она откровенно попадает под критерии на удаление. Если сомневаетесь, лучше спросить на Мете или в чате.

> А как понять когда уже можно приступать к удалению?

Когда много согласных и выслушено мнение несогласных, если таковые есть, и сделаны выводы. Если сомневаетесь, можно спросить в чате.

> Как привлечь внимание к вопросу для удаления, если он будто "повис в воздухе"? Ведь здесь по сути требуется решение "да" или "нет". Может просто стоит спросить Николаса и модераторов в общем чате?

Пинать активных участников в общем и модераторов в частности — верный путь. Иногда из-за сложности случая или необходимости в специальных знаниях участники могут надеяться, что кто-то другой, более знакомый с темой, разберётся без них. Но общими усилиями можно разобраться всегда.

> Если ли у нас какие-то чёткие критерии "ордера на удаления", кроме как спросить Николаса или модераторов в общем чате?

Не понял вопрос. *Критерием* на удаление является выполнение двух условий:

1. Добавляет ли метка что-то содержательное к вопросу? Это определяет полезность метки для фильтрации, подписок и т. п.
2. Является ли слово однозначным? Это определяет возможность применения метки вообще, количество споров вокруг применения, провоцирование оффтопика.

У нас тут имитация демократии, поэтому Николас единолично решения обычно не принимает. Обращаться исключительно к одному админу — не слишком логично.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! "Когда много согласных" достаточно неопределённое утверждение. А сколько именно это "много", где именно чёткий критерий, что определённое кол-во уже достаточно много, чтобы удалять?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov когда есть явный перевес. Вот, [пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5593/176217).

Comment: @alexolut Хорошо, допустим у вопроса 3 (4, 5 и т.д.) голоса за. Вроде перевес. Достаточно ли он явный? На нашей мете часто бывает что вопрос сильно много "за" не набирает и потом забывается.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov если вопрос *забылся*, но при этом не имеет голосов против, считаю, что можно действовать :)

Comment: @alexolut Да ладно. Даже если 0 голоса за (ну и против тоже) и вопрос забылся? А по поводу голосов против, тоже странно выходит. Допустим 1 голос против и 4 (5, 6 и т.д.) "за", то можно? Какое соотношение считается оправданным? Тем более бывают голоса против без комментариев и пояснений.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov при полном безразличии сообщества, наверное, лучше ничего и не трогать, т.е. тоже стать  безразличным. Для принятия решения есть здравая логика и математика. Если есть сомнения - задать новый вопрос, или отредактировать старый, сходить в чат. Фиксировать какие-то цифры чревато, т.к. всё течет, всё изменяется. Как вариант можно было бы явно прописать в предложении что-то вроде "будет считаться принятым при положительном балансе голосов на такую-то дату".

Comment: @alexolut *при полном безразличии сообщества, наверное, лучше ничего и не трогать* — кроме "всем пофиг" есть вариант "никто не разобрался" и, вероятно, другие. И даже если имеет место быть безразличие, то это повод задуматься о рациональности, конечно, но не однозначная причина ничего не предпринимать. В конце концов кому-то нравится заниматься мелкой слегка полезной фигнёй.