# Убрать метку [developer]

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Нужна ли нам метка [developer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/developer)? Я считаю, что она не может привнести никакого дополнительного смысла в задаваемый вопрос и является такой же общей и заведомо оффтопичной, как и недавно выпиленная метка [программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Comment: Я за. А программирование выпилили зря...

Comment: Все, что нужно для удаления метки – убрать ее из всех существующих вопросов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky сначала сообщество должно согласиться с таким предложением. Может прозвучат какие-то доводы за сохранение метки.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Метка аннигилирована. Developer'ы канули в Лету.