# Удалить и занести в чёрный список метку [grid]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, удаление-метки

Метка [grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid) является совершенно неоднозначной и может использоваться для любых UI-библиотек любого языка программирования. Используется для вопросов на любой вкус: по [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) и т.д. Предлагаю её удалить как совершенно бесполезную.

Comment: Удалить не пойдёт. Предлагай тогда полную схему замены - где и на что менять.

Comment: @Qwertiy Заменить вижу смысл только где это явно относится к модулю [tag:css-grid] и это далеко не везде где есть [tag:grid]. Я просто предлагаю удалить, так как нет никакой дополнительной нагрузки в этой метке. А может вы обоснуете какой в этой метке смысл?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov если бы метки точно, 100% однозначно указывали бы на применяемую технологию - то не было бы никакого смысла во множественных метках. Например, [tag:.net] является совершенно неоднозначным, и может быть использован на любом вопросе, от [tag:asp.net] до [tag:wpf]. Его тоже стоит удалить?

Comment: @PashaPash [tag:.net] конкретная и специфичная вещь, а что такое [tag:grid]? Это же совершенно безликая вещь. Между прочим на английском собрате метка grid в описании содержит слова "This tag is ambiguous, please don't use it."

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov [tag:grid] в сочетании с меткой конкретной технологии, наоборот, добавляет смысла. [tag:wpf] [tag:grid] - это вполне конкретный вопрос про гриды под WFP. Предлагаете заменить это на [tag:wpf-grid]? зачем?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov простой пример - у вас на вопросе стоит метка "обсуждение". это может быть обсуждение на любую тему. но обсуждение + удаление-метки - это вполне конретная тема. вы пытаетесь заменить механизим множественных меток, которые создают смысл именно при одноременном использовании нескольких "нечетких" тэгов, каким-то древовидным каталогом вида "css", "css-grid". следующим шагом обычно является предложение не ставить "css" на вопросы с "css-grid" (т.к. уже упомянут css). imho, это бесполезная трата сил :)

Comment: А почему бы и нет? На enSO такая специфичная метка [wpfgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpfgrid). Если надо тоже добавим специфичную метку для каждого нужного случая.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov потому что пользоваться ей никто не будет - отлично видно по вашей ссылке - там 20 вопросов. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5634/177221 - там в конце есть про критерий удаления. Если метка [tag:grid] добавляет к вопросу с тегом [tag:wpf] что-то полезное (а она добавляет) - ее не стоит удалять. И тем более не стоит заносить ее в черный список.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid+wpf - вот вам, для сравнения широты использования. да, там в описании написано "не используйте метку". но это попытка сделать "для порядка" а не "как удобнее".

Comment: @PashaPash По поводу списка wpf+grid: просто мало людей расчистило этот большой список, а это очень много работы. Но если бы всё было бы в одной метке [wpfgrid], то это было бы намного более верно: одна специфическая метка. enSO от нас ближе к решению данной проблемы тем, что они просто признали факт этой проблемы. А у нас выходит, что даже модераторы (в лице вас, к примеру) игнорируют важность специфичности метки. А она неспецифична и по-хорошему должна быть разложена на специфичные. От того, что будет просто будет консунсус по этому поводу, это никого ни к чему не обязывает.

Comment: @PashaPash Вот просто цитата [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): "Если метка не может быть единственной меткой в вопросе, возможно, она является мета-меткой. Все метки, которые вы используете, должны в целом работать, если они являются единственной меткой в вопросе." Или вы собираетесь саботировать это правило?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Если метка не может быть единственной меткой в вопросе, **возможно**, она является мета-меткой. А, **возможно**, не является.

Comment: В справке есть ссылка на статью https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/. Вот вам прямая цитата из нее "The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe **the content of the question**. They describe some **other aspect of the question**, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.).". Метка grid на вопросе описывает **содержимое вопроса** по wpf grid? Описывает. Значит она не мета-метка.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73545/discussion-between-pashapash-and-vadim-ovchinnikov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я считаю, что лучше всего подойдут специализированные метки. И отредактировал  (рассортировал) список вопросов таким образом:

- Для вопросов, которые можно решить разными технологиями, но вопрошающему надо просто получить табличную разметку, добавил метку [grid-layout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid-layout). Это вопросы к примеру "Как лучше всего сделать такого рода разметку?" и в принципе тут могут подойти разные подходы. Если что, подобная метка существует на enSO и довольно пополярна.
- Использовал существующие метки:

  - [datagridview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datagridview) для элемент управления
    в WinForms,
  - [datagrid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datagrid) для элемента управления в WPF,
  - [jqgrid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jqgrid) для JQuery-плагина,
  - [gridlayoutmanager](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gridlayoutmanager) для вопросов, в которых упоминался собственно GridLayoutManager. Моих знаний не хватает, чтобы понять что это такое,
- Создал метки

  - [wpf-grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf-grid) для одноимённого элемента управления в WPF,
  - [gridpane](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gridpane) для элемента управления JavaFX.

---

Метка [grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid) пока существует, так как собрала ещё зоопарк самых разных вопросов, которые неясно как обработать и на какую именно метку можно заменить в них метку [grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid). Но если кто-то сможет добить этот список, то тогда можно смело удалять данную метку.

---

Также очень бы помогло добавление качественных руководств по всем упомянутым меткам для их более качественного использования.

---

Прошу редактировать данный вопрос если что-то меняется по данной ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю оставить метку в покое и не трогать.

Эта метка достаточно хорошо описывает содержимое вопроса в случае, если она используется в паре с конкретной технологией. Вопрос по [wpf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf)+[grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid) - это вполне конкретный вопрос по работе с grid в WFP. Если бы при этом возникала неоднозачность "это вопрос про контрол grid в WFP или про использование CSS Grid в WPF" - да, метку стоило бы удалить.

Для сравнения, пара меток, которые не добавляют однозначности - [wpf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf)+[file](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file).

Да, эта метка *сама по себе* не является однозначной. Но метка и не обязана быть однозначной. Да, в справке написано

> Если метка не может быть единственной меткой в вопросе, **возможно**, она является мета-меткой.

Но там не просто так написано "*возможно*". Возможно, является, а возможно и нет. К тому же, это написано в разделе про мета-метки.

Мета-метки - это метки, описывающие не *содержимое вопроса*, а какой-то другой аспект вопроса - уровень знаний автора, мотивацию автора ([олимпиада](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0),[учебное-задание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)) или какой-то другой аспект вопроса (например, частоту появления таких вопросов на сайте - [c#-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-faq)).

[grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid) описывает именно содержимое вопроса, а не какой-то другой его аспект. Так что он не является мета-меткой.

Хотите бороть мета-метки - удаляйте метки *-faq. Например, в описании метки [javascript-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-faq) сказано, что *обычным участникам* ее на вопросы ставить нельзя. *А кому можно?*

Comment: Это ложь по поводу "Но метка и не обязана быть однозначной." основанная на слове "возможно". Фраза в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) "Все метки, которые вы используете, должны в целом работать, если они являются единственной меткой в вопросе." говорит об обратном.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вы процитировали кусок из раздела "Избегайте использования мета-меток". Я вроде бы достаточно подробно расписал,  почему grid - не метаметка и почему этот раздел к ней не применим.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov к тому же,  это предложение в справке - это просто перевод английской страницы. В английском варианте там more or less - более-менее. Метка grid более-менее работает - показывает,  что вопрос касается конкретного вида контроллер - грида. Если вас смущает перевод more or less как "в целом" - его можно исправить.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov по текущей ситуации,  вот вам цитата из справки: "Вы заменяете невнятные или непонятные метки **известными и популярными** метками, которые подходят к вопросу.". А замена grid на java-grid и wpf-grid - это наоборот,  замена популярной метки на никем неиспользуемую синтетическую.

Comment: А то что такая же метка [grid] на enSO содержит предложение не использовать вас не смущает? Или у нас тут особый случай вызванный "уникальными культурными особенностями"?

Comment: По поводу [tag:java-grid] — это какая-то странная дичь, с которой я не согласен. Но есть куча меток на enSO очень даже полезных, название которых содержит grid. Для [tag:wpf] есть довольно популярная метка [wpfdatagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpfdatagrid)

Comment: На en-so эту метку не выкосили и в черный список не занесли. Ограничились примечанием с рекомендованными мешками в описании. Не вижу,  почему мы должны активно жечьжечьжечь.  wpfdatagrid - это вполне конкретный контрол. Если какие-то вопросы заданы именно по нему - да, на них метку стоит поменять. Как и на вопросах про css grid.

Comment: Там я бы так и хотел. Заменить в каждом случае если есть что-то конкретное на более конкретную и понятную метку. Но там как раз я уверен, что именно поэтому и не сожгли, так как слишком много вопросов по этой метке созданы. Но если вопрос содержит [css] + [grid] это очень не факт, что вопрос по [css-grid]. Также и по разным комбинированным меткам. Поэтому здесь надо бы провести немалую работу специалистам из разных областей для замены меток на более внятные. Но пока нет самого важного — признания самой проблемы.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov да, согласен, если для какого-то вопроса известная и популярная метка-замена (с достаточным количеством вопросов) - стоит заменять. в противном случае - не трогать. А раз будут вопросы, на которых grid останется - значит сжигать метку не стоит. Т.е. проблема есть, но я бы сказал что она не настолько критична, чтобы активно ее бороть.

Comment: А почему не трогать, если какой-то метки ещё нет? Все метки кто-то когда-то ввёл. Ведь это нормально если я вижу определённую нишу специфических вопросов — создавать для них метку. Я просто вряд ли смогу качественно обработать вопросы по [tag:java], [tag:python], [tag:php] и может ещё каким-то. Но, допустим, если я вижу что есть определённое множество, для которого подойдёт метка — не понимаю, почему я должен это не делать.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov похожее обсуждение не так давно было по поводу меток типо [tag:option] и т.п., когда вместо них лучше просто писать [tag:html].

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov трогайте, все только за. но это не означает, что для каждого случая вы найдете более популярную и известную замену.

Comment: @Suvitruf Я бы тут поступил как и на enSO. Там сделали [tag:html-select] и [tag:html-option] там как синоним. Для SQL [tag:select] вообще бессмысленный. Именно вопросы по [tag:html-select] считаю интересной и стоящей метки нишей.

Answer (score 1):

Нет необходимости удалять и заносить в черный список. Во-первых, в метке всего 44 вопроса, не тот масштаб, при котором это вызывает проблемы. Во-вторых, метка не совсем бессмысленная, так как Grid в WPF, GridPane в JavaFX и CSS Grid выполняют по сути одну и ту же функцию: компоновка элементов интерфейса в виде таблицы. Пока метка несет хоть какую-то пользу, не надо ее удалять.

Другое дело, что есть несколько похожих понятий, которые значат совсем другое или для которых есть другие метки (некоторые - более популярные). Поэтому предлагаю сделать описание метки, разъясняющее как ей пользоваться, вроде такого:

> Используйте данную метку для вопросов по контейнерам, предназначенным
>   для компоновки элементов интерфейса в виде таблицы. Для следующих
>   понятий используйте другие метки: [datagridview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datagridview) (элемент управления
>   в WinForms), [datagrid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datagrid) (элемент управления в WPF), [jqgrid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jqgrid) (JQuery
>   plugin) и т.д.

Answer (score -1):

Сделать специализированные [java-grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-grid), [css-grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-grid) и т.п. метки, а просто [grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid) удалить.

Comment: [tag:ccs-grid] уже есть, [tag:java-grid] и т.д. я такого вообще не знаю и уверен, что не существует что-то осмысленное вроде [tag:java-grid]. Поэтому смысла не вижу в таких метках. Просто удалить тоже не пойдёт — иначе воссоздадут такую же.

Comment: Такая ситуация вообще со многими метками.

Comment: Ну это не повод всё оставить как есть. Надо всё потихоньку расчищать. Я правда не понял к какому именно предложению из моего прошлого комментария относится это утвреждение и что именно вы предлагаете этой фразой.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я к тому, что вы вопрос по конкретной метке ставите, а проблема системная. Нужно общий подход выработать для всех подобных меток.

Comment: Подобная метка является (на мой взгляд) обычной неоднозначной, а значит и бессмысленной меткой (так называемой "мета-меткой"), и поэтому просто предлагаю её удалить с занесением в чёрной список. Без неё вопросы не теряют возможность идентификации. А практика удаления бессмысленных меток у нас уже имеется.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, неоднозначная метка != метаметка.

Comment: @Qwertiy То есть то, что метка неоднозначна ничего страшного?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, ну так их же несколько ставится.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну так же не должно быть: метка должна быть полезной самой по себе. Почему это не мета-метка? Если в вопросе есть метка [grid], что это знание вам даёт? То что их несколько ставится прекрасный повод не удалять мета-метки.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вот просто цитата [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): "Если метка не может быть единственной меткой в вопросе, возможно, она является мета-меткой. Все метки, которые вы используете, должны в целом работать, если они являются единственной меткой в вопросе." Или вы собираетесь саботировать это правило?

Comment: @Suvitruf Я согласен с самой идеей, но тут метки для замены придётся выбирать очень нетривиально в данном случае. Здесь надо бы проделать намалую работу самым разным людям и каждый вопрос рассматривать индивидуально. Поясню: если вопрос содержит [tag:css] + [tag:grid], то это абсолютно не значит, что вопрос относится к [tag:css-grid]. На [tag:c#] к [tag:grid] могут относится куча разных контролов, поэтому здесь тоже важно подбирать с умом. Возможно, также придётся парочку создать, но это делать надо будет с умом.